# Field template not being recogized in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Im new to Drupal and am using the Omega theme, so I read these [instructions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) to override a field template for a `body` field in content type `article`

I placed the following file in my sub theme

field--field_body--article.tpl.php

I also tried...

field--body--article.tpl.php

field--body.tpl.php

I just have an empty file for now so I figured perhaps that it will make the body fields empty throughout the site but nothing is happening

I also flushed my cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just change underscore with a dash between field and body.

field--field-body--article.tpl.php

And don't forget to flush cache again :)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately no joy. I have that empty file there and flushed cache but the body field is still appearing eveyrwhere. (not that im trying to get rid of the body field or anything but just as a test I was hoping it would be blank)

Comment: Sorry. Could you implement hook to preprocess field an check for theme suggestions? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7